# What should my job title be, based on what I do?

Tags: title, position

I have been working at an adult education and literacy nonprofit for almost four years now and in that time my job title has been 'Nonprofit Assitant" and I am not sure if that fits what my job actually is. For context, we are a very small company and only have about five full-time and four part-time employees. We all work very closely together and help each other out.

Here are some of my duties:

- Answer phones and take messages
- Compile and enter student data
- Test Proctoring/administering for multiple testing clients
- Organizing and managing student records
- Create newsletters and complicated spreadsheets
- Basic IT work
- Create and maintain training records and certificates
- Open and sort mail
- Update and maintain our social media accounts
- Make copies
- Go through new student orientation and answer questions
- Organize inventory and prepare orders for books and other materials
- Order office supplies
- Research and prepare documents for Executive Director
- Work closely with the Executive Director on projects and fundraising
- Send out invoices for classes
- Receive and catalog cash and check payments
- Register students for classes

And so much more but that's all I can think of right now.

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace. Is there a specific reason why the title is important to you - ie you're writing a resume because you're applying for another job, or you're trying to look up comparable salaries or something else?

Comment: I am working on writing my resume and I would like to compare salaries.

Comment: David, I looked through that question and it did not help me, I am looking for specific suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Are you hoping to get your current title changed, to better reflect reality? In terms of your resume, answers to similar questions on here generally indicate that it's better to use your actual title (even if you think it's inaccurate) and then explain in the details what your actual responsibilities were.

Comment: @dwizum I am hoping to get my current job title changed.

Comment: Sounds like your a "nonprofit executive assistant" . Are you asking for us to provide you with a specific job title based on what you do?

Comment: In some cases job titles are meaningful only within the company in which they're used, and sometimes they're globally or locally recognized. In your case, it sounds to me like you're an Office Generalist, Administrative Assistant, or Administrative Coordinator.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been working at an adult education and literacy nonprofit for almost four years now and in that time my job title has been 'Nonprofit Assitant

I don't think that's a terrible job title based on your description of your duties.

For a more "general" title out of the non-profit space, you could go with something like "Office administrator" or "Administrative assistant" - maybe even "Office manager" if you feel that's a good fit for what you do.

That being said, in my experience job titles mean very little (unless they're a complete misrepresentation of what you do, but that's rarely the case.) Any future employers will be much more interested in what you *did* in that job than what it was *called*.

Answer (score 0):

Job **titles** are found in ones' **contract.**

*That* is what you were legally *hired* to do.

It is what a company would relay if asked during **background checks**.

I'm strongly against **"making up"** your own title or picking one that you think is more fitting (which is pretty much making things up in my book as well).

Some are also **protected** by guilds / associations or even the law and you'll have to meet required criteria to call yourself that.

**Now**, responsibilities evolve or promotions don't always get added in contracts and you should explain your additional duties in a paragraph or two.

Most of what you listed are btw. in an assistants job description with a bit of bookkeeping / payroll and IT / social media in the mix.

**Instead**, write about your passion, why you took the job and what were the most rewarding things you'll take with you.
What you learned and what you'll avoid.
(without criticizing your employer or their process and without giving away any trade secrets)